# writing to Ms edge through vba

Tags: vba, microsoft-edge

Is there a way where I can get to access an already open website in edge and write in it. The data is taken from an excel sheet and using VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Look at Selenium - https://www.guru99.com/excel-vba-selenium.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no COM interface available for the Edge browser. Microsoft has not provided any way to automate the Edge browser using **VBA** automation.

So, there is no way to fetch the already opened instance of the Edge browser and retrieve elements with the help of VBA.

But if you need to implement automation in Edge using VBA, you can try Selenium that already mentioned.